# Silverlight Analytics Framework and Google Analytics Events with Labels

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, google-analytics

I have successfully setup the Microsoft Silverlight Analytics Framework in both a Silverlight 4 application and a Windows Phone 7 application.

Microsoft Silverlight Analytics Framework:
http://msaf.codeplex.com/

I am successfully capturing events to Google Analytics with categories and actions.

Explanation of event tracking, categories, actions, and labels:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

What about labels? I am seeing categories and actions recorded, but not sure how to implement labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find the complete mapping in the MSAF docs:
http://msaf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Google%20Analytics&referringTitle=Home

"The Event Tracking Label field corresponds to the name of the TrackAction parent object."

Comment: Ah.. ok, so I add my desired label to teh AnalyticsEvent.ObjectName and it stats showing under labels in Google Analytics.

Thanks!